# Power shift registers input stage purpose

Tags: circuit-analysis, shift-register

Both the TPIC6A595 and NPIC6C596 power logic shift registers have the same pretty complicated input stage:

[image]

The purpose of the two MOSFETs on the right seem pretty straightforward, their function is to get the Input voltage to the nearest of the VCC and LGND.

I believe the rest of it is some kind of protection, but I don't understand how that works or what is the purpose of this circuit (at first glance it looks like the NPN transistor will create a short circuit when the Input voltage is near VCC).

Answer (score 1):

It is protection but it does not protect near VCC but far above VCC. Due to the 25V zener diode, only when voltage is above 25V, the FET will start to turn on, turning on the BJT.

Comment: The 12V Zener will clamp the input to 12V and the resistor in front of it will limit the current to (Vin-12)/R.  If Vin rises high enough, there will be too much current flowing through the 12V Zener so at 25V, the second Zener starts to conduct, which turns on the MOSFET and crowbars the input with the BJT.